# Where should I put general app config in a Gatsby project?

Tags: reactjs, configuration, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby, but familiar with CRA. I'm using the default Gatsby setup generated by running `gatsby new <project_name>` from Gatsby CLI.

I have some general config that I want run in my whole project, regardless of current page - for example:

```
import { enableMapSet, enableES5 } from "immer";

enableMapSet();
enableES5();
```

In CRA projects I put this stuff inside App.tsx, but can't figure out what the right place is in a Gatsby project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gatsby, you don't have a single configuration file *per se*. There are several APIs exposed by Gatsby that allows you to configure one specific part of your site.

To run a set of functions regardless of the page you can use a `gatsby-browser.js` (placed in the root of the project).

Basically, Gatsby exposes a bunch of APIs that lets you respond to actions within the browser, and wrap your site in additional components. The [Gatsby Browser API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis) gives you many options for interacting with the client-side of Gatsby. One of them, `onClientEntry` fits your requirements. From its documentation:

> `onClientEntry`
>
> `(_: emptyArg, pluginOptions: pluginOptions) => undefined`
>
> Called when the Gatsby browser runtime first starts.

Applied to your code, your `gatsby-browser.js` should look like:

```
import { enableMapSet, enableES5 } from "immer";
import React from 'react';


export const onClientEntry = () =>{
  enableMapSet();
  enableES5();
};
```

The snippet above will trigger `enableMapSet()` and `enableES5()` on every page.